# SSIS Script Task append a line to file

Tags: ssis

I would Like to add footer to all the files in a directory

below command works when i gave one file name .
but when i try *.csv to append footer to all the files in a directory it fails .

```
System.IO.File.AppendAllText(@"C:\Users\ibm\*.csv", "My Custom Footer");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What would you expect? [AppendAllText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143356%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) clearly states

> path
>
> Type: System.String
>
> The file to append the specified string to.

If you need to perform the same task against multiple files you will need to enumerate through all the files in a given folder

Code approximately

```
foreach(string fileName in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\Users\ibm", "*.csv")
{
    System.IO.File.AppendAllText(fileName, "My Custom Footer");
}
```